# Clickable functional diagram in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, diagram

How can I achieve this kind of diagram: 
[image]

Can I achieve this with something like charts? But it must be responsive. I've tried SVG but no success.

Answer (score 0):

the link doesn't work.
- use svg, you can attach event listeners to the svg nodes. 
- mdn is an excellent source of documentation for svg.
- have a look at d3 library.
cheers

Comment: Link is now fixed

Comment: It gives me svg in black and white not like as the colorful image.

Comment: paste the svg in your page. see that each text node is included into the node that draws its respective triangle, if not, wrap each triangle and text nodes in a <g> tag. you should have 6 of them.... give them a class name.

Comment: style the <g> tags with css animations. bind an event listener.

Comment: Here is the link of  SVG [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3VIf9ZImYwya2dsOHVMZENyMkU)

Comment: google drive sais you need to give me permission ... plz notify when done. alferaru.

Comment: Done. please check.

Comment: contents is unusable ... every entity is a polyline, every letter. no color information whatsoever

Comment: i converted it from jpeg to svg from online site.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to export the graphics in svg format.

Paste the svg in your page. See that each text node is included into the node that draws its respective triangle, if not, wrap each triangle and text nodes in a `<g>` tag. You should have 6 of them; give each of them a class name.

Style the `<g>` tags with css animations. Bind an event listener.